# R: Error while reading XLS file because of styles

Tags: r, macos, xls, xlconnect

While trying to load XLS file to R

```
people <- readWorksheetFromFile("/Users/andi/export_exp_11.xls",sheet="people")
```

I got:

```
ERROR: IllegalArgumentException (Java): Unable to set user specified style names for built in styles!le
```

When I openede the file in Excel and selected whole spreadsheet and set style to None it runs ok.
I would like to manipulate programatically this styles before reading it to R? Without using Excel of course. Is it possible?

Comment: My suggestion is not to parse `xls` files at all... going through the manual process of saving them to `csv` makes for a lot less headaches!

Comment: I download it from some web service, and don't have option to get it in form of CSV. What I of course would like;) but it is not possible.

Comment: @andi - ???  Once you have the Excel workbook, open it and select SaveAs/CSV .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It's joke? Such MANUAL solution is good when things happens ONCE. I need  full automatization.

Comment: Yeah, well, your questino lists a single file.  If you need to do this to 100 files a day, then say so. Meanwhile, try some of the other `R` packages for reading from .xls files, or write an Excel VBmacro which executes a SaveAs for all files in a directory(or all open files, whatever is easier for you).